# Devpi-Postgres: Cannot upload large files

Tags: database, postgresql, devpi

I am getting the following error while uploading files bigger than 1 GB to devpi using postgres.

> pg8000.exceptions.DatabaseError: {'S': 'ERROR', 'V': 'ERROR', 'C': '54000', 'M': 'out of memory', 'D': 'Cannot enlarge string buffer containing 0 bytes by 1391196735 more bytes.', 'W': 'COPY files, line 1, column data', 'F': 'stringinfo.c', 'L': '303', 'R': 'enlargeStringInfo'}

Any idea how I could solve this issue ? Thanks

I have tried using the `--max-request-body-size`, and increased the `max_wal_size` in postgres, but keep getting the following error:

Update:

- I using a python script along with twine to upload the files.
- Postgres version 16.2.
- The table definitions are generated by devPi.
- Currently, the problem comes up while uploading a file which is about 1350 MBs large

Comment: You cannot store values of that size in PostgreSQL. For a better response, you have to provide more detail.

Comment: Could you please tell me what more details that I could add ?

Comment: Your programming language, the PostgreSQL API you are using, the table definition, the size of the problematic values, the code you use to store these data.

Comment: If you really want to store files inside the database, you can use large objects, using large objects: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/lo.html

Comment: @FrankHeikens, but I guess devPi doesn't allow that. Right ?

Comment: Please show the table definition and the code that tries to insert the data.